# Is there a TFS check-in policy for Nunit and NCover?

Tags: tfs, nunit, ncover

I would like to enforce my users to run unit tests and code coverage,
but we are using Nunit and NCover, not MS Team system unit test\ coverage framework.

How canI do it? Is there a matching check-in policy?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The MSTest policy works by checking that there is a TestResults folder that has been created since the last checkout, and that the TestResults includes the specific test list to check.

You don't really have a way to check this when doing NUnit, since NUnit doesn't leave any artifacts behind after a test run, which means doing something similar to the MSTest check is going to be a little hard.